# Overloading + operator with classes containing array pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am currently writing a "Polynomial" class in order to practice Operator Overloading. I have successfully overloaded the stream extraction and insertion operators, but I am having some trouble with the "+" operator.

My class has a private pointer that proceeds to create an array in the constructor. I understand how one would overload the "+" operator with a complex number class, for example, but I'm getting confused with this program.

Guidance in finding a solution would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

#ifndef POLYNOMIAL_H
#define POLYNOMIAL_H

class Polynomial 
{
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial& p);
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial& p);
      public:
             Polynomial(int = 10);
             ~Polynomial();
             void assignExponent();
             Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& other);

      private:
              int SIZE;
              int *exponents;
              int *polyPtr; //***************
};

#endif

//CONSTRUCTOR
Polynomial::Polynomial(int arraySize)
{
     if(arraySize > 0)
                  SIZE = arraySize;
     else
     {
         cout << "Array size must be greater than 0. Program will now "
              << "Terminate..." << endl;

         system("pause");
         exit(0);
     }

     polyPtr = new int[SIZE]; //*********************
     exponents = new int[SIZE];

     for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
             polyPtr[i] = 0;

     assignExponent();
};

//DESTRUCTOR
Polynomial::~Polynomial() //******************
{
     delete [] polyPtr;                         
};

//STREAM INSERTION
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Polynomial& p)
{
         for(int i = 0; i<p.SIZE; i++)
         {
               in >> p.polyPtr[i];  //*************        
         }

         return in;
};

//STREAM EXTRACTION
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Polynomial& p)
{
         int exponent;
         for(int i = 0; i<p.SIZE; i++)
         {
               exponent = (p.SIZE - 1) - i;

               if(p.polyPtr[i] != 1)
               {  
                  if(exponent > 0 && exponent != 1)
                           out << p.polyPtr[i] << "x^" << exponent << " + ";  

                  if(exponent == 1)
                           out << p.polyPtr[i] << "x" << " + ";

                  if(exponent == 0)
                           out << p.polyPtr[i];  
               }

               //In order to not display coefficient if = 1
               else
               {
                   if(exponent > 0 && exponent != 1)
                           out << "x^" << exponent << " + ";  

                   if(exponent == 1)
                           out << "x" << " + ";

                   if(exponent == 0)
                           out << p.polyPtr[i];
               }    
         }       

         return out;
}; 

//Assigns a value for exponent
void Polynomial::assignExponent()
{
     for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
     {
             exponents[i] = (SIZE - 1) - i;        
     }
};

//OVERLOAD OF + OPERATOR
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial& other)
{
         Polynomial sum(SIZE);
         int difference;

         //If the first polynomial is larger
         if (SIZE > other.SIZE)
         {
            difference = SIZE - other.SIZE;

            for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
            {
                 if(i - difference < 0)
                      sum.polyPtr[i] = polyPtr[i];

                 else
                 {
                     sum.polyPtr[i] = polyPtr[i] + 
                                  other.polyPtr[i - difference];  
                 }                            
            }         
         }

         //If the second polynomial is larger       **PROBLEM**  
         if(other.SIZE > SIZE)
         {
            difference = other.SIZE - SIZE;

            for(int i = 0; i<other.SIZE; i++)
            {
                 if(i - difference < 0)
                      sum.polyPtr[i] = other.polyPtr[i];

                 else
                 {
                     sum.polyPtr[i] = other.polyPtr[i] + 
                                  polyPtr[i - difference];  
                 }                            
            }         
         }

         //If the polynomials are equal
         if(SIZE == other.SIZE)     
         {
                  for(int i = SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--)
                  {
                          sum.polyPtr[i] = polyPtr[i] + other.polyPtr[i];        
                  }   
         }

         return sum;
};

int main()
{
    int polySize;

    //User enters a size for the first & second polynomial
    cout << "Enter a size for the first polynomial: ";
    cin >> polySize;
    Polynomial pOne(polySize);

    cout << "\nEnter a size for the second polynomial: ";
    cin >> polySize;
    Polynomial pTwo(polySize);

    //User enters in values (Overload of >> operator
    cout << "\n\nEnter in values for the first polynomial, "
         << "in the format - (x x x x): " << endl;
    cin >> pOne;
    cout << "\nEnter in values for the second polynomial, "
         << "in the format - (x x x x): " << endl;
    cin >> pTwo;

    //Overload << operator for output
    cout << "\nPolynomial 1 is: " << pOne << endl
         << "Polynomial 2 is: " << pTwo << endl;

    Polynomial pThree = pOne + pTwo;

    cout << "\nAfter being added together, the new polynomial is: "
         << pThree << endl;

 system("pause");   
}
```

I have updated my current code because I did not think opening another question would be the best way to go. Anyway, in trying to line up my polynomial's to be added, I've partially succeeded. The only problem that arises is when the second polynomial, pTwo, is larger than the first. I've labeled the section of code, **PROBLEM**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should follow the rule of three. Even better, use a vector.

Comment: Mind the fact that you're doing `Polynomial pThree = pOne + pTwo;` before even declaring `pOne` and `pTwo`

Comment: @Andy Prowl - Just fixed that, thanks.

Comment: Hint: Using pencil and paper, how do you add (x^3 + 2x^2 + 3x + 5) + (x^2 + 4x + 6)?  So what should your program do first to add `{1,2,3,5}` and `{1,4,6}`?

Comment: @aschepler - you're right, I need to start at the top.

Comment: I've changed it to `for(int i = SIZE-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @aschepler: How would I go about lining the numbers up correctly if I am adding together arrays of different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `+` should write like below:

```
class Polynomial 
{
  // ...

  Polynomial operator+(const Polynomial& other);

 // ...
};

Polynomial Polynomial::operator+(const Polynomial& other)
{
     Polynomial sum(SIZE);

     for(int i = 0; i< SIZE; i++)
     {
         sum.polyPtr[i] = polyPtr[i] + other.polyPtr[i];
     }

     return sum;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Now I am having trouble returning the array. Like so: `return Polynomial(newPoly[]);` thanks

Comment: @Ericafterdark: It's better to do not return when `+`. `void`

Comment: You can't use the variable `SIZE` as an array size.  `operator+` should return the sum.

Comment: So I don't have to return then?

Comment: Thank you. The only error I receive now is: `invalid conversion from 'Polynomial*' to 'int'` When I try to return sum.